# How does Pig sample 1TB data by a ratio like 0.0001 effectively?

Tags: algorithm, apache-pig

How does pig implements the sample method ? Can I sample the data out by simply reading through all the data only one time?

Edit:
I have found an article talking about this topic. http://had00b.blogspot.com/2013/07/random-subset-in-mapreduce.html  It helps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, one pass of the data is enough for sampling it with any ration (let it be `r`), using [Reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling):

```
Let k = SIZE * r //SIZE is the size of input array
Let R be the result array (of size k), and S be the original (input) array
//first populate the first k elements or R with first k elements of S
for each i from 1 to k:
    R[i] = S[i]
//then, choose randomly if and which element from R to replace with the new candidate
for each i from k+1 to SIZE:
   j = random(1,i) //uniformly distributed number between 1 to i
   //insert the new element at probability i/k, instead one of the existing elements
   if j < k:
       R[k] = S[i]
return R
```

At the end, each element had a probability of `k/SIZE = r` to be picked

Comment: Thanks. But how can I sample 1TB data using this method on Hadoop?

Comment: @Canoe One approach will be to let every reducer output `k` samples in first phase, as described above. This will give you `#reducers*k` samples. In a 2nd map-reduce phase, you choose the final `k` samples out of the `#reducers*k` candidates. While it seems to be 2-pass algorithm, recall that #reducers and k are relatively small - so the 2nd phase is much quicker.

Comment: when data sizes and k are both big that we cann't fit data into mapper memory, this method fails.

Comment: @Canoe 0.0001PB is only 100MB. this should not be an issue in 2014

Comment: but when ratio is bigger…  I have found an answer in the link I added fits all condition well